# how to compile libsecret file for git whereas I don't have this folder in my git installation

Tags: git, credential-providers

I have got version > 2.11 and I need to use a credential manager.
I read that I need to use libsecret :

```
sudo apt-get install libsecret-1-0 libsecret-1-dev
cd /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret
sudo make
git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret
```

But git installation was made without using yum because my git version wasn't available as a package for red hat 7.9. so we compiled the source.

Git is working great but I don't have this folder :
/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret

So I can't do the make command.

What is the solution ?

Comment: This belongs on superuser.com, but in general you must obtain the sources for *all* the packages you're missing, and compile and install them all in the right order.

Comment: I downloaded GIT sources and I found the missing directory in the sources. I will check if I'm able to do the make on this folder that is not the official one (not present in /usr/share/doc/git/contrib....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compiled from sources, then just `cd` to where you cloned the code or extracted the tarball, then `cd contrib/credential/libsecret` and run Make from there. And adjust the path to the built credential helper accordingly.